# How to obtain devices connected to my router using nbtstat command?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

i use this command to get the name of a computer in my network (nbtstat -a [192.168.1.5]). it works fine when that device is a pc, 
but when i try to get a cellphone's name using the same command it says Host not found. 
but i'm sure the device is in my network and when i ping the device it works fine. so what is the difference between a laptop and a cellphone that i cannot get the correct result?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have something specific that you're expecting as "the cellphone's name"?

Answer (score 1):

The `nbtstat` command is for doing NetBIOS over TCP/IP lookups and testing.

From the docs (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc940106.aspx):

> The `nbtstat -a <name>` command performs a NetBIOS adapter status
>   command on the computer name specified by `<name>` . The adapter status
>   command returns the local NetBIOS name table for that computer as well
>   as the MAC address of the adapter card. The `nbtstat -A <IP address>`
>   command performs the same function using a target IP address rather
>   than a name.

If you run `nbtstat -A` with an IP that doesn't have NetBIOS over TCP/IP, (typically Windows File Sharing or something similar like Samba), it's not going to respond to the adapter status command.

Comment: Oh, i get it now. is there another way i can get the name of the device from it's ip address? (i'm using windows 8)

Comment: If the device left a hostname with the DHCP server, and the DHCP server is configured to update a DNS server with DHCP requested hostnames, you could try a DNS reverse lookup: e.g. `nslookup 8.8.8.8`